# How to create method parameters for custom SOAP Web service in Powershell?

Tags: java, web-services, powershell, soap, wsdl

I'm working with some SOAP-based Web services (Opsware Twister, to be more specific) via New-WebServiceProxy cmdlet (obviously) and encountered some difficulties when providing parameters for methods I call - it results in typecasting error. Here's the code:

```
$user = "myuser"
$passw = Get-Content "z:\creds.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString

$hpsa_core = "core.dom.loc"

$creds = [PSCredential]::New($user, $passw)

$URI_ss = "https://$hpsa_core/osapi/com/opsware/server/ServerService?WSDL"
$ws_ss = New-WebServiceProxy -URI $URI_ss -Credential $creds -Namespace 'ns_ss'

$URI_search = "https://$hpsa_core/osapi/com/opsware/search/SearchService?WSDL"
$ws_search = New-WebServiceProxy -URI $URI_search -Credential $creds -Namespace 'ns_search'

$hostname = "SQLSERVER1.dom.loc"
$objectType = "device"
$expression = "ServerVO.hostname CONTAINS $hostname"

$filter = [ns_search.Filter] @{
    objectType = $objectType
    expression = $expression
}

$refs = $ws_ss.findServerRefs($filter)
```

The problem is, that findServerRefs method expects not a primitive type, but another class (com.opsware.search.Filter), and methods to create its instance are not exposed via the service. This straightforward approach doesn't work, resulting in error:

> Cannot convert argument "filter", with value: "ns_search.Filter", for
>   "findServerRefs" to type "ns_ss.Filter": "Cannot convert the 
>   "ns_search.Filter" value of type "ns_search.Filter" to type
>   "ns_ss.Filter"." At line:36 char:1
>   + $refs = $ws_ss.findServerRefs($filter)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodArgumentConversionInvalidCastArgument

SearchService is implemented as Java interface (com.opsware.search -Interface SearchService)

Am I using the wrong approach?

One important remark: there is an integration component for Powershell from the vendor (DLL) which provides an easeir experience, but I want to achieve the same results with pure Powershell functionality (if it is possible at all).

Answer (score 0):

Replacing this fragment

```bsh
$filter = [ns_search.Filter] @{
    objectType = $objectType
    expression = $expression
}
```

with this one

```bsh
$filter = [ns_ss.Filter] @{
    objectType = $objectType
    expression = $expression
}
```

will probably do the job.

## **Update:**

Found the cause of this problem: **[Bug in New-WebServiceProxy cmdlet when using -Namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746036/bug-in-new-webserviceproxy-cmdlet-when-using-namespace)**

In short, you must save script as a file and invoke that way (Using `&` operator, or as a command line argument: `powershell.exe -File script.ps1`).

Comment: no, it generates the same typecast error, only with "ns_ss" context.

Comment: @Max My guess was based on the fact, that each call to `New-WebServiceProxy` cmdlet generates an independent dynamic assembly, — they do not share any types. Error message was indication of that. But now, if it still does not work, I have no more ideas...

Comment: @Max See updated answer. This is most unnatural and annoying PowerShell bug I've ever seen.